# Copy one pointer content to another

Tags: c, pointers

I thought I've read somewhere that when using pointers and we want to copy the content of one to another that there are two options:

- using memcpy or
- just assigning them with = ?

However in the lower example, I just tested it by allocating memory for two pointers, then assigning the second, changing first..but then the entry of my second pointer is also changing.. What am I doing wrong :/.

```
typedef struct {

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} my_struct;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    my_struct* first = malloc(sizeof(my_struct));   
    first->a = 100; first->b = 101; first->c = 1000;

    my_struct* bb = malloc(sizeof(my_struct));  

    printf("first %d %d %d\n", first->a, first->b, first->c);
    bb = first;
    printf("second %d %d %d\n", bb->a, first->b, bb->c);


    first->a = 55; first->b = 55; first->c = 89;
    printf("second %d %d %d\n", bb->a, first->b, bb->c);
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The moment you do `bb = first;`, `bb` and `first` are pointing to the same location of memory. `first->a = 55; first->b = 55; first->c = 89;` will change the values for `a`, `b`, and `c` in that location. The original value of `first`, is still lingering in memory but no way to access it anymore.

I think what you may want to do is `*bb = *first;`.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot for the explanation, it made it a little bit more clear..
But what is the convention in C about doing the content copying, is memcpy more common or the assignment you wrote?

Comment: I don't think there is a convention _per se_. It really depends on the scenario as, copying data involving pointers, is quite the advanced topic, IMO.

Comment: So with `*pointer = *other_pointer` I **always** have a guarantee that the content behind the `other_pointer` is copied to the location of `pointer`?

Comment: ...The original value of bb is still lingering in memory..

Answer (score 13):

Your knowledge about `memcpy` is correct but you cannot assign contents of "**location pointed to by the pointers**" just by assigning pointers like you did in your statement mentioned above.

You are assigning one pointer to the another in the following statement:

```
bb = first;
```

Now both these point to the same memory location (think of `bb` as an alias to `first`).

If you want to copy data then you copy using "**data pointed to by pointers**" `*bb = *first`

Comment: Ok, so there is no way around of using memcpy in these cases?

Comment: @malajedala `*bb = *first;`

Answer (score 5):

As has already been pointed out, if you have a pointer `first` that points to some location in memory, and you make the assignment `bb` = `first`, where `bb` is a compatible pointer type, then `bb` points to the same address as `first`. This does not copy the contents of the memory referenced by `first` to the location originally referenced by `bb`. It copies the value of the pointer, which is an address, to `bb`.

If you define an array `A`, you can't make the assignment `B = A` to copy the contents of `A` to `B`. You must use `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` or some such function. But structs are different. You can assign the contents of one struct to a compatible struct.

In your example, `bb` and `first` are pointers to structs, and when you write `bb = first`, now both pointers reference the same address in memory, and you no longer have access to the memory originally referenced by `bb`-- so now you have a memory leak! But `*bb` and `*first` are structs, and when you write `*bb = *first`, the contents of the struct `*first` are copied to the struct `*bb`. So now you have two different structs, at different locations in memory, each with copies of the same three `int`s.

If your `my_struct` type contained a pointer to `int`, then after the assignment `*bb = *first` they would each contain a copy of a pointer to the same location in memory, but the data referenced by those pointers would not be copied. So, if the structs contained a pointer to an array, only the pointer would be copied, not the contents of the array, which would be shared by the two structs.

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the data pointed by pointers like `*p1 = *p2`. But Remember, this will not work if you have pointers again inside the structures you are copying.